# How to create dashboard with CSV file in Azure or Azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have github repo inside that I have csv file and I have to create  data visualization dashboard based on csv  data in azure. I tried with creating pipeline in azure Devops but it's only showing test pass and fail value. Can we create such a dashboard in azure?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow! In its current form, your question is not a good fit for SO. It's not clear what it is you're trying to achieve. Please take some time to take the [tour] and read [ask]. On-topic: in general, DevOps is not the place to visualize data from a CSV. If the CSV contains information about the code or repo, please provide more information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't have a widget that supports to import data and create dashboard in Azure devops.